How C# handle COM interfaces with generics?
I wonder how C# compiles COM interfaces like this:
[ComImport]
[Guid(...)]
public interface IFoo<T> { ... }

How is T handled from pure C/C++ side (without MS extensions)? Does it use template or is it just replaced with IUnknown and what happens if the method returns T?

COM cannot understand generics. You can implement a COM visible class that implements a COM visible generic interface in .NET (it will compile fine) but it just won't be visible at all to COM clients, it won't be exposed by the .NET Core class factory, and you won't be able to create a .TLB either. See here for .NET Framework https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms229590(v=vs.100)
